# Verifying inequality using differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be non constant differentiable function.
> If $f'(x)=(e^{f(x)-g(x)})g'(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$
> and $f(1)=g(2)=1$, then which following statement is/are True.

$(a)\ f(2)<1-\ln(2)$

$(b)\ f(2)>1-\ln(2)$

$(c)\ g(1) >1-\ln(2)$

$(d)\ g(1)<1-\ln(2)$

From above  differentiable equation

$\displaystyle e^{-f(x)}f'(x)=e^{-g(x)}g'(x)$

$\displaystyle \int e^{-f(x)}f'(x)dx=\int e^{-g(x)}g'(x)dx$

$\displaystyle -e^{-f(x)}=-e^{-g(x)}+C$

$\Longrightarrow e^{-g(x)}-e^{-f(x)}=C\cdots (1)$

Put $x=1,$ We get $\displaystyle e^{-g(1)}-e^{-f(1)}=C$

$\displaystyle e^{-g(1)}-e^{-1}=C\cdots (2)$

Put $x=2,$ We get $\displaystyle e^{-g(2)}-e^{-f(2)}=C$

$\displaystyle e^{-1}-e^{-f(2)}=C\cdots (3)$

Now I did not understand how I find value of $C$ and How can I find correct option

Please have a look

Answer (score 2):

$e^{-g(1)}-e^{-1}=C$

$e^{-1}-e^{-f(2)}=C$

Since the right-hand sides of the previous equalities are equals, also the left-hand sides are equals, hence

$e^{-g(1)}-e^{-1}=e^{-1}-e^{-f(2)}$

$e^{-f(2)}+e^{-g(1)}=2e^{-1}$

Consequently,

$e^{-f(2)}<e^{-f(2)}+e^{-g(1)}=2e^{-1}$

therefore,

$e^{-f(2)}<2e^{-1}$

$-f(2)<\ln\left(2e^{-1}\right)$

$-f(2)<\ln2-1$

$f(2)>1-\ln2$

Analogously, we get that

$g(1)>1-\ln2$